# ImageResizer and image files without an extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I've been using [ImageResizer.net](http://imageresizing.net) just fine in our web app, but now I need it to resize and serve images that don't (and cannot) have a file extension, like this one:

```
http://localhost:58306/ClientImages/Batch/2012/12/10/f45198b7c452466684a4079de8d5f85f?width=600
```

In this situation, I know that my files are always TIFF's, but they wont have a file extension.

What are my options?

/resizer.debug.ashx: https://gist.github.com/raw/9c867823c983f0e5be10/4db31cb21af8b9b36f0aa4e765f6f459ba4b309f/gistfile1.txt

## Update

I followed Computer Linguist's instructions:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Config.Current.Pipeline.PostAuthorizeRequestStart +=
            delegate
                {
                    var path = Config.Current.Pipeline.PreRewritePath;
                    var clientImgsRelPath = PathUtils.ResolveAppRelative("~/ClientImages/");
                    var isClientImageRequest = path.StartsWith(clientImgsRelPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                    if (isClientImageRequest)
                        Config.Current.Pipeline.SkipFileTypeCheck = true;
                };


                // other app start code here
    }
```

`http://localhost:58306/ClientImages/Batch/2012/12/10/92d67b45584144beb5f791aaaf760252?width=600` just responds with the original image with no resizing.

This was also asked about here: http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/cache-non-images#comment-571615564

This is happening during development with the Cassini or Visual Studio web server or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 2):

**First, you MUST be using IIS7 Integrated mode. Classic mode will not work; it does not permit ASP.NET access to extensionless requests**

ImageResizer can't know that extension-less URLs are images unless you explicitly tell it.

This doc explains:

http://imageresizing.net/docs/howto/cache-non-images

Essentially, you'll end up performing logic (usually String.StartsWith) on your URLs to find out if ImageResizer should treat the file as an image.

```
Config.Current.Pipeline.PostAuthorizeRequestStart += delegate(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context) {
  string path = Config.Current.Pipeline.PreRewritePath;

  //Skip the file extension check for everything in this folder:
  if (path.StartsWith(PathUtils.ResolveAppRelative("~/folder/of/images"), 
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){

        Config.Current.Pipeline.SkipFileTypeCheck = true; 
  }
};
```

You should register this event handler in Application_Start in global.asax.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `&process=always` to force treatment as an image?